# Puppet Create/Install Windows Service

Tags: puppet

Pretty new to Puppet... here is what I am trying to accomplish:

1. Copy a powershell script, exe and config file locally and then execute the powershell script, which does the following:
2. creates the service based on the copied exe, and the exe leverages the config file for settings

from what I gather, puppet can't natively create a Windows service.  I am looking for a breakdown on how to accomplish this

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Powershell you also have the [New-Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849830.aspx) commandlet available. You could also use [sc.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx) to create a service, or maybe the old Windows 2000/2003 tools [Srvany.exe and Instrsrv.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/137890).

Comment: Additionally, if your executable is a self-written .NET app, you can also embed an installer in the executable such that it can install itself. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf(v=vs.110).aspx